# SQL Server 2012 Service not starting (Probably related to Service Agent issue)

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have an application (Dynamics AX 2012) that can't connect to the SQL server.  I log onto the SQL server, and open SQL Server Management studio and can't connect to the database engine.

I check the Sql Server configuration manager and all the services except SQL server browser are stopped and I can't start any of them.  In the Windows log I get this message:
The service did not start due to logon failure.

I imagine this has something to do with something wrong with the service agent that is assigned for this service.  How can I fix this problem?  I don't remember setting up a password for the account or anything when installing SQL Server and I'm not sure where to look to get this going.

I've gone through the Service window and just type in what I think the password is for the SQL Server Agent and SQL Server.  SQL Server doesn't give me an error but SQL Server Agent says the account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified.

Comment: Can you try changing the service logon to local instead to see if it lets you start the service?

Answer (score 0):

Launch SQL Server Configuration Manager, then select SQL Server Services, then access the properties of each service, then configure the credentials on the Log On tab.

Comment: Done that and it gives the error message that I state in my original issue.  "Account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified".

Comment: You have to use a valid account for which you know the password. Instead of trying to guess what the password is for the existing account, use a different account or change the password for the existing account.

Comment: From what I've read there is no password for those service accounts, I was able to go back to the SQL Server service and set it to this same service account and it worked.  On the SQL Agent it fails.

Comment: Well you haven't actually specified which accounts were in use. I assumed you were using accounts that were created specifically for SQL.

Comment: I'm not even sure which service the SQL Server Agent should use.  If I create one on a domain, what do I need to do to configure it correctly?